# Why can't I update metadata on an SPFile object?

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

According to [Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile.properties.aspx):

> The Windows SharePoint Services 3.0
>   object model supports updating file
>   metadata. You can use an indexer on
>   this property to set a value. For
>   example, to set the value of the
>   MyDate property for a given file to
>   the current date and time, use the
>   indexer and call the Update method, as
>   follows:
>
> [Visual Basic]
>
> oFile("MyDate") = DateTime.Now
>
> oFile.Update()
>
> [C#]
>
> oFile["MyDate"] = DateTime.Now;
>
> oFile.Update();

But when I write the line of code:

```
oFile["Test"] = "test";
```

It errors out with:

> Cannot apply indexing with [] to an
>   expression of type
>   'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFile'

Am I doing something wrong or did Microsoft screw up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have SharePoint to try it on right now, but it looks like sample is wrong. I believe it should be `oFile.Properties["Test"]="test";` as the article talks about Properties property.